# Sending email with Script Task in Foreach Loop errors on SMTP connection manager

Tags: ssis, html-email, etl, ssis-2012, foreach-loop-container

I have a Foreach Loop container with a Send Mail Task using an SMTP Connection Manager that successfully sends emails. I need to send HTML emails and understand that the Send Mail Task won't do that. I've added a Script Task to incorporate HTML text in the body of the email but the script errors with

> The remote name could not be resolved

Using the same SMTP Connection Manager that works in the Send Mail Task. How can I send multiple emails to a list of email addresses? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

the entire error:

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Failure sending mail.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       at ST_209a900aa97949759ea05ad934ade067.ScriptMain.Main() in c:\Users\sschildt\AppData\Local\Temp\2\Vsta\e2ae5c29103d447fad1855720cffe591\ScriptMain.cs:line 117
  InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       HResult=-2146233079
       Message=The remote name could not be resolved: 'SmtpServer=xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.edu;UseWindowsAuthentication=True;EnableSsl=False;'
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
            at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
            at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(ServicePoint servicePoint)
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
            at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
       InnerException:
```

THE SOLUTION:

```
#region Namespaces
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;          // Added
#endregion

namespace ST_ccd5e092bfdc417c8c29f1c22c390108
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {

        public void Main()
        {
            String SendMailFrom = Dts.Variables["mailfrom"].Value.ToString();
            String SendMailTo = Dts.Variables["mailto"].Value.ToString();
            String SendMailToName = Dts.Variables["mailname"].Value.ToString();
            String SendMailSubject = Dts.Variables["mailsubject"].Value.ToString();
            String SendMailBody = Dts.Variables["mailbody"].Value.ToString();
            String SendMailAttach = Dts.Variables["vattach"].Value.ToString(); 
            SendMailBody = SendMailToName + ",<p>" + SendMailBody;

            String SmtpServer = Dts.Connections["SMTP Connection Manager"].Properties["SmtpServer"].GetValue(Dts.Connections["SMTP Connection Manager"]).ToString();

            // Create an email and change the format to HTML
            MailMessage myHtmlFormattedMail = new MailMessage(SendMailFrom, SendMailTo, SendMailSubject, SendMailBody);
            myHtmlFormattedMail.IsBodyHtml = true;

            // Create a SMTP client to send the email
            SmtpClient mySmtpClient = new SmtpClient(SmtpServer);

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SendMailAttach))
            {
               // 
            }
            else
            {
                myHtmlFormattedMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(SendMailAttach));
            }
            mySmtpClient.Send(myHtmlFormattedMail);

            // Close Script Task with success
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }

        #region ScriptResults declaration

        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you have not posted the complete error log, but you can try something like this:

```
private static void sendEmail()
    {
        // Change below parameters
        string ToEmailAddress = "toemailaddress";
        string FromEmailAddress = "fromemailaddress";
        string FromEmailPassword = "fromemailpassworda";
        string EmailSubject = "Email Subject";
        string SmtpServerName = "smtpservername";
        string LogoFilePath = @"SomeLogoPicturePathWithFileName";
        int PortNumber = addportnumberhere;

        try
        {
            var mail = new MailMessage();

            // Email Text HTML
            StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
            mailBody = CreatEmailBodyTextHtml(LogoFilePath);

            // Add Logo
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = mailBody.ToString();
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(getEmbeddedImage(LogoFilePath, mailBody.ToString()));

            // Send Email
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient(SmtpServerName);

            mail.From = new MailAddress(FromEmailAddress);
            mail.To.Add(ToEmailAddress);
            mail.Subject = EmailSubject;

            SmtpServer.Port = PortNumber;
            SmtpServer.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FromEmailAddress, FromEmailPassword);
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = false;
            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
        }
        catch (Exception s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

    }

private static StringBuilder CreatEmailBodyTextHtml(string imgPath)
    {
        StringBuilder mailBody = new StringBuilder();
        mailBody.AppendFormat("<h1>Hi, This is a Test Email.</h1>");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("Dear Sir/Madam, ");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("<br />");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("<br />");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("With Regards");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("<br />");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("<br />");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("Tester.</p>");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("<br />");
        mailBody.AppendFormat("<img src=\"" + imgPath +"\">");

        return mailBody;
    }
public static AlternateView getEmbeddedImage(string filePath, string mailBody)
    {
        LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(filePath);
        res.ContentId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string htmlBody = @"<img src='cid:" + res.ContentId + "'" + "width= \"700\" height = \"300\"" + @"/>" + mailBody;
        AlternateView alternateView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(htmlBody, null, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
        alternateView.LinkedResources.Add(res);
        return alternateView;
    }
```

It works for me with gmail and with my SMTP server.

You can change the sendEmail method to accept toEmailAddress and call this in a loop. The toEmailAddress can come from a txt file, SQL Database table or something else.

 
I tried the above code with below sample data using Gmail SMTP and I received the email within 1 secound.

```
string ToEmailAddress = "xyzto@gmail.com";
string FromEmailAddress = "xyz@gmail.com";
string FromEmailPassword = "addyourpassword";
string EmailSubject = "Email Subject";
string SmtpServerName = "smtp.gmail.com";
string LogoFilePath = @"someimagepathwithfilename";
int PortNumber = 587;
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, unfortunately I get namespace errors on the 'StringBuilder' and 'NetworkCredential' calls.

Comment: Please see my answer, I have added the definition of method getEmbeddedImage and also a sample data from gmail SMTP server which I tested today. I received the email within seconds. Let me know if it works for you. Thanks

Comment: I removed the getEmbeddedImage as I didn't need it but the StringBuilder still errors.

Comment: Ok. Could you please post the error logs or the error full description? Are you using the namespace <using System.Text;> at the top? If you do not need any file attachment or picture, use the function call without parameter <mailBody = CreatEmailBodyTextHtml();> and remove the same in function definition.

Comment: @SSchildt: Can you please update me if it worked for you?

Comment: No it did not. I found another solution.